# $_GET parameter after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am attempting to use my `.htaccess` and mod_rewrite to redirect requests for mp3 files inside a directory called `download` to a PHP file called `download.php`. This file makes a Google Analytics request and then does a server side redirect to the actual mp3 file located in the `files` directory.

The rewrite should specify the mp3 name as a url parameter which I can access from the PHP via $_GET. However this isn't working.

My .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*download/(.*)\.mp3$ /download.php?url=http://static.example.com/files/$1.mp3 [QSA]
```

The `download.php` file is executed but if I do `var_dump($_GET);` it returns with `array(0) { }`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have `MultiViews` enabled, disable it by using this line on top of .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.